# rails: how do i access a method in my application controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Noob scoping issue, I imagine.  :\

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  @locations = get_locations

  def get_locations
    Location.where(:active => true).order('name').all
  end

end
```

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `get_locations' for ApplicationController:Class
```

Two questions:
1) What's with the error? Am I calling the method incorrectly?
2) How do I access this method from a sub-classed controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `get_locations` within the class scope, but the method is an instance method, not a class method. If for example you used `def self.get_locations` then you would be providing a class method, one of which you can use within the class scope (after you have defined it, not before like you're doing).

The problem here is the logic, what is this method for? What do you intend to use `@locations` for? If it's to go inside your application view, then you should put this method into the `ApplicationHelper` module, and call it from inside the relevant action. If you'd like it in another view on another controller and you'd like to use `@locations` inside your `locations` method, perhaps your setup might look something like this:

**PagesController**

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  def locations
    @locations = Location.where(:active => true).order('name').all
  end
end
```

**locations.html.erb**

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= # do something with 'location' %>
<% end %>
```

If you'd like to use this inside of your `application.html.erb` you can simplify it quite some..

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def locations
    Location.where(:active => true).order('name').all
  end
 end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<% locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= # do something with location %>
<% end %>
```

The answer boils down to logic, and to really figure out exactly what you're looking for, more details would probably be required.

Comment: I need @locations available to my application layout, but also to another controller.  Best spot to put this?

Comment: If you need to access it in your application layout then your application controller is probably the best place to put it as it'll be available across your controllers. Have your controller call `before_filter` on your `get_locations` method to populate the `@locations` instance variable

Answer (score 3):

You're calling it from the class scope, not from an instance scope.  more likely what you want is the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :setup_locations


  private
  def setup_locations
    @locations = Location.where(:active => true).order('name').all
  end

end
```

To make your original example work, you'd need to make #get_locations defined on self (which points to the class at definition), like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  @locations = get_locations

  def self.get_locations
    Location.where(:active => true).order('name').all
  end

end
```

The problem with that code is that @locations will only be available from the class level as a class instance variable, which is comparable to a static variable in most other languages, and which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Oddly enough, the second example generates the exact same error. The first example seems to work fine -- but this would limit my ability to call this method from another controller, right?  (thanks for your help!)

Comment: It would, but if you want to use the same method from other controllers, you put it in your application controller, which should be the base class for your controllers anyway (ApplicationController subclasses ActionController::Base typically)

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that this line:

```
@locations = get_locations
```

... is trying to access the class level method `get_locations` and not the instance method.

The clue here is that the error message is showing that it can't find it on the **class** itself (ApplicationController:Class) and not an instance of that class. That means that you're in the class scope, not instance scope.

This would fix it:

```
  def self.get_locations
     Location.where(:active => true).order('name').all
  end
```

Comment: @@locations is almost certainly not what you want.  Its a true class variable, which in Ruby is shared between all instances of the class, *including subclasses* and can have some really weird consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Even the question is quite old, you can also call your controller action anywhere just by calling:

```
ApplicationController.new.get_locations
```