# ApplicationController helper method undefined in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to write a simple helper method that checks if a user's email address contains a specific domain name. The method is needed in all my controllers and depends on the state of `current_user`, so I felt the best place to put it would be in my ApplicationController. Depending on the evaluation of the method on line 3, a second helper method is called. I modeled my setup on [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381511/4139179).

When I insert this code and refresh the page, the `binding.pry` should be hit, indicating that the helper method I defined is being evaluated, but this doesn't happen. Instead, `:disable_intercom?` evaluates to true without hitting the method below. If I remove the colon, I get an error saying `disable_intercom?` is undefined. What am I missing here?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include if :disable_intercom?

    private

    def disable_intercom?
        binding.pry
        if user_signed_in?
            current_user.email.split('@').include?('mysite.com') ? true : false
        else
            false
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here are a few other StackOverflow discussions on this issue I found. I've tried the various solutions proposed, but nothing seems to trigger the `disable_intercom?` method.

[conditionally apply skip_before_filter with :if => condition in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345738/conditionally-apply-skip-before-filter-with-if-condition-in-rails-4)

[skip_before_filter ignores conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637110/skip-before-filter-ignores-conditionals)

Comment: skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :disable_intercom?

Comment: I get an error saying `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: did you get the colon after if? It should be "if:"

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. `skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :disable_intercom?` always evaluates `:disable_intercom?` as truthy.

Comment: I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345738/conditionally-apply-skip-before-filter-with-if-condition-in-rails-4) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637110/skip-before-filter-ignores-conditionals) on this same issue, but the solution still doesn't seem clear. I've tried implementing the various answers propose, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21755636/525478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that `skip_after_action` does not accept a conditional argument such as `if:` or `unless:`. Even if you pass a conditional, the `skip_after_action` callback always executes.

Unfortunately for me, this means that it is not possible to do what I wanted to do with the code. I'm looking into other ways to conditionally disable the Intercom API, since using a conditional `skip_after` callback isn't a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
 skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include if :disable_intercom?
```

With:

```
 skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: :disable_intercom?
```

In your initial code, which is valid ruby, you're basically always skipping because you dont pass `if` as an option to `skip_after_action`, you trigger the line when the symbol is truthy, ie always

Comment: I get an error saying `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: sorry, ediited my answer

Comment: From what I understand after some further digging, `skip_after_action` will always evaluate regardless of the condition you pass it. If I just replaced `:disable_intercom?` with `true`, the conditional is still skipped. What I ended up doing is changing the callback to `after_action :disable_intercom`. Then in `disable_intercom?` I call `intercom_rails_auto_include` if a user is signed in and their email address matches the criteria.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH please consider submitting your solution as an answer, rather than a comment.